# JavaCV configuration in Android Studio

Tags: android, javacv

I know there is a lot of similiar questions to this, but a lot of them seem to be out of date because of the development of libraries such JavaCV.

I used the code from [Video Creation with Images and Audio in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775173/video-creation-with-images-and-audio-in-android) to create movie, but I have a problem with lib imports.

I did as JavaCV page says, I put dependency in gradle :

```
compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '0.9'
```

now, I don't know if I have to do something else?

I have used these imports :

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;

import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage;
```

and get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:387)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat.<clinit>(avformat.java:13)
        at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:106)
        at voidstudio.app.activity.CreateMovieTask.doInBackground(CreateMovieTask.java:46)
        at voidstudio.app.activity.CreateMovieTask.doInBackground(CreateMovieTask.java:21)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
```

and

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jniavutil from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/voidstudio.app-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/voidstudio.app-1]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:521)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:535)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:410)
```

did I missed sth in configuration? I have seen similiar questions but there was no proper answer for this.

Comment: Nope, maybe this problem is related to new version of JavaCV

Answer (score 8):

Update! I've also found out that if you have have an armeabi-v7a folder in the jniLibs, or are using anything other than an armeabi folder, you will have issues with the .so files not being added.

Looks like ffmpeg is not being imported. I had the same problem. Here is what I did. Let me know if this helps you!

```
compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '0.9'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.9-0.9', classifier:    'android-arm'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.3-0.9', classifier: 'android-arm'
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with gradle dependencies but from where do you get versions for ffmpeg and opencv (version: '2.4.9-0.9', version: '2.3-0.9')

Comment: I just looked on MavenCentral. Here is a link to the FFMPEG one. It looks like there is a new version that was released in December. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg

Comment: I'm using version 0.11 of javacv and replaced 'opencv' and 'ffmpeg' with the latest version i found in maven central. But still does not work. I do have a folder armeabi-v7a under my src/main which contains other .so files. Do I have to do anything about the armeabi-v7a folder?

Comment: I was unable to use gradle and had to manually import everything as a library. This way, I could move all of the armeabi files that javacv uses armeabi-v7a.

Answer (score 2):

## Check the placement of `jniLibs` folder

I have just changed the placement of my jniLibs (before it was outside main folder) and this worked for me, please check the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmQ3v.png)! hope this will help