# Android : FFmpegFrameRecorder (JavaCV) UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I am trying to record video using `OpenCV` with some overlayed data. I have added `OpenCV` to my project and get camera preview successfully. While searching for how can I record video I came across to `JavaCV`. `JavaCV` has a sapmle activity called `RecordActivity` to demostrate video recording. It adds a `CameraView` dynamically with code and get camera frames and record them in `onPreviewFrame` method of the `CameraView`. You can see the full code here:

[RecordAvtivity.java](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/RecordActivity.java)

What I want to do is record video in `onCameraFrame` metod of the `CvCameraViewListener2` interface instead of `onPreviewFrame` metod of the `PreviewCallback`.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Core.flip(rgba, rgba, 1);
    // Overlay some text and record video here.
    return rgba;
}
```

JavaCV record code block from RecordAvtivity.java

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    if (audioRecord == null || audioRecord.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return;
    }

    int i = imagesIndex++ % images.length;
    Frame yuvImage = images[i];
    timestamps[i] = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

    /* get video data */
    if (yuvImage != null && recording) {
        ((ByteBuffer) yuvImage.image[0].position(0)).put(data);

        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "Writing Frame");
            long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

            if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                recorder.setTimestamp(t);
            }

            recorder.record(yuvImage);
        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`JavaCV` needs data as `byte[]` but I have `Mat` object. I need to cenvert between them efficiently.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE:**

I have used following solution to solve my initial problem

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Core.flip(rgba, rgba, 1);

    if (data == null) {
        data = new byte[(int)rgba.total() * rgba.channels()];
    }

    rgba.get(0,0, data);
    record(data);
    return rgba;
}

public void record(byte[] data) {

    if (audioRecord == null || audioRecord.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return;
    }

    int i = imagesIndex++ % images.length;
    Frame yuvImage = images[i];
    timestamps[i] = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

    /* get video data */
    if (yuvImage != null && recording) {
        ((ByteBuffer) yuvImage.image[0].position(0)).put(data);

        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "Writing Frame");
            long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

            if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                recorder.setTimestamp(t);
            }

            recorder.record(yuvImage);
        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but now I am getting following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.yceo.anlatbana, PID: 17622
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:390)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:358)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1407)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.yceo.anlatbana.GameFragment.initRecorder(GameFragment.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.yceo.anlatbana.GameFragment.onCreate(GameFragment.java:98)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1939)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:988)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I have tried solution from below question but it didn't work:

[JavaCV configuration in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660828/javacv-configuration-in-android-studio)

I have also tried both manual and gradle install for JavaCV but none of them worked.

I am using:

- Android Studio 1.4
- OpenCV 3.0
- JavaCV 1.0

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/4761/mat-to-byte-array/

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: Yes. But I have tried to disable it, didn't work.

Comment: @EdsonMenegatti I have minifyEnabled false in build gradle

Comment: Could you paste your compile calls that add javacv?

Comment: Where can I find them?

Comment: I faced a very similar issue in the past before, and I [documented a solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13139808/176769). Let me know if this fixes the problem you are having so I can write an appropriate answer.

Comment: Which version of android api level you're using? I had this problem with api level 23 and a downgrade to 22 solves my issue.
See this issue: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/245

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to dependencies

```
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.0.0-1.1:android-arm'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:2.8.1-1.1:android-arm'
```

and add packagingOptions inside android {}

```
packagingOptions{}
```

and add these lines to packagingOptions

```
exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.properties'
exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.properties'
exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.xml'
exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.xml'
```

It's working for me. hope it's helpful for you.